# Convert guid bytes to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket, byte, guid, arraybuffer

I am getting arrayBuffur from WebSocket connection, and I can get range of byte arrays that is 
Guid created in c#.

**How I can convert this guid bytes to string in javascript?**

Guid="FEF38A56-67A9-46DF-B7D8-C52191CD70F4"

Bytes=[86, 138, 243, 254, 169, 103, 223, 70, 183, 216, 197, 33, 145, 205, 112, 244]

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/dalaqa/guid/blob/master/javascriptGuid the exact representation of C# GUID from byte array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to JohanShogun answer, a simple script to do that would utilize map function on an array of bytes. However, according to Remarks section of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.guid.tobytearray.aspx , first four bytes should be reversed, as well as two next and two after them. So... here's correct solution (don't forget about zero-padding of resulting values 15 should be "0F" not "F"):

```
var x = [168, 199, 56, 91, 146, 52, 231, 64, 175, 133, 167, 15, 146, 60, 83, 107];

// reverse first four bytes, and join with following two reversed, joined with following two reversed, joined with rest of the bytes
x = x.slice(0, 4).reverse().concat(x.slice(4,6).reverse()).concat(x.slice(6,8).reverse()).concat(x.slice(8))

var guid = x.map(function(item) {
    // return hex value with "0" padding
    return ('00'+item.toString(16).toUpperCase()).substr(-2,2);
})

// guid variable now holds string: 5B38C7A8349240E7AF85A70F923C536B
```

Testing example here: http://jsbin.com/ogegut/4/edit

Comment: Hmm..Bytes and guid is correct I have just verified. Why it can be different, any thoughts ?

Comment: First, big thanks for your help and Yes, it work for example guid. But for another is missing one symbol in length, it equal 15 in final string but must be 16. GUID_BYTES=[168, 199, 56, 91, 146, 52, 231, 64, 175, 133, 167, 15, 146, 60, 83, 107] , GUID="5B38C7A8-3492-40E7-AF85-A70F923C536B". Bytes and guid is ok, I checked.

Comment: It's because I didn't add padding to hex-ish values, hence byte 15 is converted to just "F" instead of "0F". I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: This helped a lot. In my case, the GUID was returned as raw binary data, but you can convert it to an array with `var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(binaryData);` then proceed with WTK's code.

Comment: Instead of `.substr(-2,2)` use `.slice(-2)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using these as Numbers (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp) you can simply do .toString (16) to get them in hex.